# VBA Issues Pulling Info From Web and Putting It in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a script to pull doctor reviews from vitals.com and put them into an excel sheet.
It worked well when I just pulled the review, but when I added for it to pull the date as well, it will print the first review and date, then loads for a while, and then crashes. I'm new to all of this so I'm hoping there are some glaring mistakes I am not seeing. I just can't seem to find a way to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim DocCounter As Integer
  DocCounter = 2
  Dim Go As String
  Go = "Go"

  If IsEmpty(Cells(1, 4)) And Cells(1, 3).Value = Go Then

    If IsEmpty(Cells(DocCounter, 1).Value) Then GoTo EmptySheet
    Do

      Dim Reviews As String
      Reviews = "/reviews"

      Dim IE As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
      Set IE = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

      Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
      IE.Open "get", "http://vitals.com/doctors/" & Cells(DocCounter, 1).Value & Reviews, True
      IE.send

      While IE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
      Wend

      Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

      Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
      Dim HTMLBody As MSHTML.HTMLBody
      Set HTMLDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
      Set HTMLBody = HTMLDoc.body
      HTMLBody.innerHTML = IE.responseText

      Dim ReviewCounterString As String
      Dim ReviewCounter As Integer
      ReviewCounterString = HTMLDoc.getElementsByName("overall_total_reviews")(0).getElementsByTagName("h3")(0).innerText
      ReviewCounter = CInt(ReviewCounterString)

      'Pull info from website loop'
      Dim RC As Integer
      RC = 2

      Dim sDD As String
      Dim WebCounter As Integer
      WebCounter = 0

        Do
          sDD = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("date c_date dtreviewed")(WebCounter).innerText & "-" & HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("description")(WebCounter).innerText
          Cells(DocCounter, RC).Value = sDD
          WebCounter = WebCounter + 1
          RC = RC + 1
          Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        Loop Until WebCounter = ReviewCounter

      Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
      DocCounter = DocCounter + 1
      If IsEmpty(Cells(DocCounter, 1).Value) Then GoTo Finished

    Loop

Finished:
    MsgBox ("Complete")
    End Sub

EmptySheet:
    MsgBox ("The Excel Sheet is Empty. Please add Doctors.")
    End Sub

  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: "...and then crashes" - Does it give any errors? If so, what error at what line?

Comment: No it does not. Excel just freezes up and then crashes. I don't get an error. Sorry if this is a stupid question but is there a way I can find if there was an error after I reopen excel?

Comment: either go step by step (via break points) or use `Debug.Print` at several points with increasing values for loops... then check the output while the macro runs... also I suggest to do a `DoEvents` inside the `Do ... Loop Until WebCounter = ReviewCounter` loop to avoid freezing which also should be `>=` istead of simply `=`... if `ReviewCounter` is `0` your excel will freeze (which I suggest is the case here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `Cells(DocCounter, RC).Value = sDD` the `Worksheet.Change` event gets triggered again and the macro starts over again, until the call stack is full (I think).

Add

```
 Application.EnableEvents = False
```

at the start of the macro and

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

at the end. That way the event will not be triggered during the macro.

Edit: You should probably also think about if it's really necessary to run the macro every time anything is changed anywhere on the sheet. You could check `Target` (the range that was changed) first to see if the change makes it necessary to reload the data.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! Its running smoothly now!

Comment: @MattMicko I added a little something to my post. Are you sure you need the data to be reloaded every time you change something on the sheet?

Comment: Thanks! I added a button instead so it will update the reviews when I click it.